# How to Streaming audio base on WiFi and RTSP in Android?

Tags: android, audio, streaming, rtsp

I want to develop an **RTSP server on Android** that it can streaming audio from Android device to another Android device.

This APP can select the music from SD card , and streaming to the other devices which in the same network.
SO the application of this  is `RTSP Server`.

I have search for `RTSP Server on Android` , but the information is not clear for Android or it only for Client.

I am new to this , **can someone help and give me some information for **develop RTSP server on Android*** ?*

**Like how to encode the music from local ? and How to streaming audio to the other devices ?**

Thanks in advance.